# Route only HTTPS Connections through TOR

Tags: linux, networking, security, proxy, tor

I want to create an tor router on my network using an extra computer I have (2011 Mac Mini). Since the exit node can read/modify traffic that is not end-to-end encrypted, I would only like to route HTTPS traffic through tor and connect directly to the source for all insecure traffic.

This leaves me with 2 questions:

- What does this do to the benefits provided by TOR? I imagine nothing because if the traffic is not end-to-end encrypted anyway, TOR provides almost no benefit and it is trivial to find identifying information if you are the exit node. Does this compromise the integrity of the TLS-enabled traffic though timing or confirmation attacks?
- How would I set this up? I am by no means a linux guru. If this does provide benefit, what are the steps to route all incoming traffic either through TOR or direct to source based on whether the traffic is TLS-enabled?

Comment: [Related.](https://superuser.com/questions/165425/is-content-routed-through-tor-encrypted?rq=1)

Comment: I have a pretty thorough understanding of how TOR works. My question is more related to the intricacies of standing up an ad hoc network to accept connections and based on whether they are using TLS, routing them through TOR (local SOCKS proxy) or direct to source. Also any flaws in this method that I may have overlooked.

Comment: So you want to decide on-the-fly whether you create an encrypted connection or an unencrypted connection and route it accordingly? I didn't find a solution but maybe some setting in `torrc` or `iptables` allow you to reroute traffic like you want.

Comment: Correct. And I imagine I can, but that's what I'm unclear on what to do since I honestly don't have much experience messing with unix config files. I may just end up writing a go app that can handle it for me..